# .htaccess issues with redirect all except certain folders

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I know there are a lot of these types of questions here, along with other tutorials and I have tried many of the proposed solutions but for some reason they are not working for me 100%. Here is the list of things that I would like the htaccess file to handle

- redirect to http://example.net/ if not requesting /admin/ directory
- redirect to http://example.net/ if not requesting /about-us.html file
- redirect to http://example.net/ if request does not end in: .jpg, .jpeg, .png, .gif, .css, .js
- redirect https:// to http://
- do not allow hotlinking
- do not allow directory index listing (Options ALL - Indexes)
- do not allow .htaccess file visibility

The biggest issue I seem to have is allowing the admin directory and the about-us.html file. It still redirects to the site's root. Here is what I have so far.

```
<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/about-us.html$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin/*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(gif|jpeg|jpg|png|css|js)$
RewriteRule (.*) / [R=302]

Options All -Indexes
```

Where am I going wrong with this? Thanks in advance for all your help and insight.

Comment: I don't see how this rule will redirect `/about-us.html` to site root. Do you have other rules as well?

Answer (score 3):

okay, one by another:

> do not allow .htaccess file visibility

Your Files directive seems okay, however, this should always be placed in the server-wide configuration file and not in .htaccess itself. And you should consider to hide all files starting with a dot. Additionately, "Satisfy all" ensures to keep these files unaccessible even when user are authenticated by means of HTTP authentication schemes.

```
<Files ~ "^\.">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Satisfy all
</Files>
```

> do not allow directory index listing (Options ALL - Indexes)

All you need is "Options -Indexes"

> do not allow hotlinking

Check the referer:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^($|https?://(www\.)?example\.net)
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpe?g|png|css|js)$ - [R=403]
```

If the referer is not empty AND does not contain an url of example.net then send a http/1.0 403 Forbidden. Remember that you cannot rely on the referer header. It may not be there, in this case you must allow access to don't block your own page, if given it may be wrong, but then you may argue that this is the visitor's responsibility.

> redirect http:// to https://

It should normally be the other way around, to ensure your visitors are safe by using ssl/tls. But here you are:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) http://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Its even better to configure the virtual hosts appropriately.

> redirect to http://example.net/ if not requesting /admin/ directory
>   redirect to http://example.net/ if not requesting /about-us.html file 
>   redirect to http://example.net/ if request does not end in: .jpg, .jpeg, .png, .gif, .css, .js

The easiest way is to use the rewrite chain and to allow special requests (tagged with [L] als last rule) before redirecting all remaining:

```
RewriteRule ^/?admin/                 -  [L]
RewriteRule ^/?about-us\.html         -  [L]
RewriteRule \.(jpe?g|png|gif|css|js)  -  [L]
rewriteRule ^/?(.*)    http://example.net/$1    [R=302]
```

(BTW: If you have moved pages to a new url always use R=301 (moved permanently) as redirection code, so that google and other search engines don't handle both urls as duplicate content.)

And use RewriteBase to set the preceding Base directory (in your case just "/").

Your full .htaccess file looks like:

```
Options -Indexes

<Files ~ "^\.">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Satisfy all
</Files>

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^($|https?://(www\.)?example\.net)
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpe?g|png|css|js)$ - [R=403] 

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^admin/                        -  [L]
RewriteRule ^about-us\.html                -  [L]
RewriteRule \.(jpe?g|png|gif|css|js)       -  [L]
rewriteRule ^(.*)    http://example.net/$1    [R=302]
```

edit (due to a msunderstanding):

The above example works well for an **external redirect to a different domain** (here example.net). If there shall be only a **local redirect on the same domain** (e.g. to "/"), you need to replace the last rule by:

```
Rewriterule ^$    -     [L]
RewriteRule ^.*   /     [R=302,L]
```

to prevent redirect loops.

Comment: When I try this I get a and infinite redirect loop in my browser. I'm not sure where the issue might be. This is obviously a thorough solution and I greatly appreciate it. But with my experience I cannot find the issue.

Comment: I made a mistake in the regular expresion for the referer check, it's corrected now

Comment: @robotsushi: An infinite loop could appear if the server is configured to redirect to https normally (server-wide configuration), or if your target domain (example.net) has the same document_root/directory like the original one. This .htaccess is only intended for the original domain.

Comment: You should also check that you have no html meta tags that may redirect the browser back to the old domain.

Comment: thanks so much for your dilligence with this. I have copied the current version and still get a redirect loop error. I should mention that there is no redirect intended for a previous domain to go to the current domain. There is only one domain involved. I have commented out different sections of this htaccess file and still get the redirect loop error.

Comment: I assumed you wanted to redirect to a different domain, not to the DirectoryIndex on the same Domain, a misunderstanding, But the difference is only two lines, I've just added this info to my answer above.